# Creating new row after every 10th set in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, jstl, fieldset

Right now i got a map of the following structure which i pass it to my JSP page.

```
Map<String,List<String>> tapeMap = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
```

In My JSP page , i am iterating through the Map and value to have a show hide structure

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
   <tr>
        <td class="reportrow2">
        <c:forEach items="${tapeemap}" var="detFieldEntry">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${empty detFieldEntry.key}">
                <c:set var="defValue" value="Uncategorized"/>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <c:set var="defValue" value="${detFieldEntry.key}"/>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
        <div class="hideable">
            <a class="hide" href="#"><c:out value="${defValue}"></c:out></a>
            <div class="hide-container">
     <c:forEach items="${detFieldEntry.value}" var="item" varStatus="status">
          <fieldset> 

            <input type="checkbox" name="tape_id" id="tape_id" onClick="this.value='<c:out value='${item}'/>'"/>
            <c:out value="${item}"></c:out>
           </fieldset>
    </c:forEach>
    </div>
</div>
    </c:forEach>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to form a  structure similar to this

```
+ electronics

      [] RF1  [] RF6
      {} RF2  [] RF7
      [] RF3  [] RF8
      [] RF4  [] RF9
      [] RF5  [] RF10
```

So during iteration , for the every 10th item new row needs to be created.i tried using tr td tags .But the results were not exact.so kindly suggest me a good solution to achieve this .I went through with the following question previously asked but it doesn't work

[1]: [JSTL create a new row every 5th fieldset in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485974/jstl-create-a-new-row-every-5th-fieldset-in-a-loop)

Kindly suggest me on how to achieve this.Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Think about `modulo % operator`  , increment a variable every iteration and check `if ($variable%5==0)` to move to next five elements.

Your first 5 elements should be in a `div` , the seconde in an other `div`.

Your first div should have a `style='float:left;width:200px'`

Comment: Sorry i forgot jstl due to a little practice but this is how it should be done

Comment: @ FaceOfJock i have previously tried using the modulo operatior.but it went in vain .I tried some thing like this                     <c:forEach items="${detFieldEntry.value}" var="item" varStatus="status"><c:if ${item.index%10 eq 0}><div id="tagLeft"></c:if>
          <fieldset> 

            <input type="checkbox" name="tape_id" id="tape_id" onClick="this.value='<c:out value='${item}'/>'"/>
            <c:out value="${item}"></c:out>
           </fieldset><c:if ${(item.index+1)%10 eq 0}></div></c:if>
    </c:forEach>